# Generate random 2D polygons

Tags: python, random, computer-vision, computational-geometry

I would like to generate some random shapes that are regular polygons with right angled (Like a floor plan) only.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. One approach is to train a GAN model to do it but is there a algorithm to do that?
I was thinking to generate as follows

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Such random shapes would not be _regular polygons_.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xList = []
yList = []

oX = random.randint(0, 100)
oY = random.randint(0, 100)

ooY = oY
ooX = oX

for i in range(3):  
  
  xList.append(oX)
  yList.append(oY)
  
  if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
    nX = random.randint(0, 100)
    nY = oY
  else:
    nX = oX
    nY = random.randint(0, 100)
    
  xList.append(nX)
  yList.append(nY)

  oX = nX
  oY = nY
  
if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
  xList.append(oX)
  yList.append(ooY)
else:  
  xList.append(oY)
  yList.append(ooX)


plt.scatter(xList, yList)
plt.show()
```

This would not work entirely for your purpose, however I think you can easily edit it too. This generates random co-ords with right angle connections to each other, then plots it using matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

this kinda works

```
import pygame, random, numpy, time

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

def generatePoly(startingpos, stepsize, blockyness, limit):
    def gen():
        poly = []

        stepSize = stepsize
        # center of screen
        startingPos = startingpos
        currentPos = startingPos[:]
        axis = 0
        changeDirChance = blockyness
        # steps limit
        trySteps = limit


        poly.append(currentPos[:])
        while 1:
            #return to pos before collision
            undo = currentPos

            currentPos = undo[:]
            if not random.randrange(0, changeDirChance):
                axis = random.randrange(0, 2)
            themove = random.choice([-stepSize, stepSize])
            currentPos[axis] += themove

            #check collision
            if currentPos in poly:
                try:
                    del poly[-1]
                    del poly[-1]
                    currentPos = poly[-1]
                except Exception:
                    pass
            poly.append(currentPos[:])

            # if in the same x or y
            if currentPos[0] == startingPos[0] or currentPos[1] == startingPos[1]:
                #if line has changed direction at least once
                # 1/20 change of exit
                if not random.randrange(0, 21):
                    break


            if trySteps < 0:
                # square
                return [(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 10), (0, 10)]
            trySteps -= 1


        return poly

    # the more blockness, the more it generates a single stright line (very ew)
    thepoly = gen()

    # detect stright line
    while 1:
        thepoly = gen()
        thenumpy = numpy.array(thepoly)

        if (thenumpy[:, 0]-startingpos[0]).any() and (thenumpy[:, 1]-startingpos[1]).any():
            break

    return thepoly


currentPoly = generatePoly([400, 300], 10, 100, 10000)
print("Enter: generate another poly\nSpace: save image")
while 1:
    #currentPoly = generatePoly()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                #center of the screen
                currentPoly = generatePoly([400, 300], 10, 100, 10000)
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                pygame.image.save(window, "output.png")
                print("==========")
                print("saved!")

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    if len(currentPoly) > 2:
        pygame.draw.polygon(window, (0, 0, 0), currentPoly)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

sorry if it's a little messy